# Power-off on CPU-intensive task

Tags: linux, windows, memory, cpu, crash

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'm a bit lost at the moment:

I recently looked into [this](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) project which is quite memory and cpu intensive. Everytime I start a calculation my computer just turns off completely (like it does when there is a shortcut somewhere and the fuse goes off) - no error message or the like. This is under Ubuntu, but these crashes randomly started to happen on Windows also (also without any bluescreen), so I assume that it's not a driver issue but a hardware one (altough my CPU, RAM and motherboard are all quite new). I haven't changed any hardware in the near past.

I'm a bit lost now because I don't have any indication of what is going wrong and I'm also not aware of any logs or similar things that could help me. It strongly smells like a hardware failture in my opinion but even if it is one I don't know WHICH hardware (but I belive that the GPU isn't involved) and I don't know where to look, so I'm asking you guys if you have any experience on this and could give me a hint where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happens when doing CPU-intensive tasks I would suspect overheating, either because a fan is stuck or broken (old computers), or because the thermal paste is badly applied or the heatsink is incorrectly installed (new computers).

It's easy enough to check for: there are software temperature monitors that can graph the temperature and sound alarms. If the hardware is new, you may have a CD with motherboard drivers and monitors ready to install.

Comment: Just checked under Linux. Under stress, my CPU happily crawls up to 90°C in a matter of seconds before giving up >.> God this was so obvious, thanks a lot

Comment: 90° is not good, correct! If it's a malfunctioning fan the correction should be easy, if the problem is the installation of the cooling elements you may want to go see the people who provided the computer. Thermal paste isn't extremely expensive but a tube is good for several applications.